# i cant seem to access values inside an overriden method(a custom listener)

Tags: android-fragmentactivity

so i have a listener that listens for  typed text from the main activity in a search-view and  gets that data to a fragment of the same main activity. the above process is working well problem is i cant seem to access the data from the overridden listener to the rest of the fragment class so i can actually use it .
 here is the listner instance

```
private void getSearch(){
    searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSearchViewShown: searchview running");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {
            logoRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Log.d(TAG, "onSearchViewClosed: 0000");
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


            Log.d(TAG, "VALUE"+ newText);

            listner.onDataLoaded(newText);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

here is the fragment class in which i need the text values to be seen. the data value is what i need to use. also declaring a global variable and then assigning it to this value doesn't work as it returns null, i'm thinking its because the overridden method somehow gets called before the oncreatview of the fragment does but i'm not sure. any help would be largely appreciated, i have been on this for the past 4 days, i'm really getting desperate

```
  @Override
public void onSearchViewSelected(String newText) {

}

@Override
public void onDataLoaded(String data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "query" + data);

}
```

Comment: I don't get what exactly your problem is. Please specify what exactly are you trying to access from where. And how. So far I don't even know if `listner` references the correct listener or if you're trying to get data into `onDataLoaded` or from it to somewhere else.

Comment: i got it thanks , though :)

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem by doing it the other way around, getting what i needed to the method instead of the opposite and it worked